# Stripping prefixes and suffixes from shell words matching a pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I'm reading a line of input, which will contain a number of words which all start with `is_tokenized_` and have a suffix starting with `:TKN_`; my goal is to strip these prefixes and suffixes.

I've tried `awk -v RS=" " -F'[_:]' '{print $3}'`, but this doesn't work if the name contains underscores itself.

---

Example input:

```
is_tokenized_Firstname:TKN_NAME is_tokenized_Last_Name:TKN_NAME
```

Expected output:

```
Firstname Last_Name
```

Comment: EXPECTED is in second line ,sry fr the typo!

Comment: First, include an English-language description of the desired logic, as opposed to an example alone. Second, we expect you to show your own effort here. What have you tried, and how does it fail?

Comment: Some examples of pertinent questions you haven't answered: Is the only prefix you want to strip `is_tokenized_`, and the only suffix `:TKN_NAME`? What should happen to content with other prefixes, or other suffixes? Is the content coming from a stream, or in a shell variable? How much content are we talking about? (Short streams are more efficient to handle natively in shell, longer sequences with external tools). Etc.

Comment: Also, which shell, specifically? Does an answer need to conform to POSIX sh, or are ksh or bash features acceptable?

Comment: Will your input always be on exactly one line? If not, is the example given accurate in implying that more than one token can be present on a single line of input?

Comment: @Charles:  1)My prefix that needs to be removed is always "is_tokenized_" and the suffix is always is ":TKN_*"

Comment: @charles: i am using bash features

Comment: @Charles: My input is always one line where records are seperated with space.

Comment: @charles: I tried this but the `awk -v RS=" " -F'[_:]' '{print $3}' but the problem is if field name also has underscore then I am unable to retriew the value.

Comment: @sampatkumar: These should all go into the question (you should [edit] it).

Answer (score 2):

```
s='is_tokenized_Firstname:TKN_NAME is_tokenized_Last_Name:TKN_NAME'
read -r -a words_in <<<"$s"                    # Read words into array
for word in "${words_in[@]}"; do               # Iterate over input
  [[ $word = is_tokenized_*:TKN* ]] && {       # Check for match
    word=${word#is_tokenized_}                 # Strip prefixes
    word=${word%:TKN*}                         # Strip suffixes
  }
  printf '%s ' "$word"                         # Write output
done
printf '\n'
```

[Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is an appropriate tool for this job. See also [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) ("How do I do string manipulations in bash?").

- Using `read -a` reads words into an array split by characters in IFS (by default, spaces, tabs and newlines); this allows easy operation on each word of input.
- Using `[[ $string = $glob ]]` checks for whether a string matches a glob-style pattern (for an exact string equality check, `[[ $string = "$string2" ]]` would need to be used instead).
- `${word#prefix}` expands the variable `$word`, removing `prefix` from the beginning.
- `${word%suffix}` does likewise, for a suffix on the end.

---

Another approach, since your shell is bash, is to use regular expressions:

```
re='^is_tokenized_([^:]+):TKN_'
s='is_tokenized_Firstname:TKN_NAME is_tokenized_Last_Name:TKN_NAME'
read -r -a words_in <<<"$s"
for word in "${words_in[@]}"; do
  [[ $word =~ $re ]] && word=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  printf '%s ' "$word"
done
printf '\n'
```

This works because doing a regular expression match with the `=~` operator sets the `BASH_REMATCH` variable to an array for which the second item (at index 1, following index 0) is the first matching group from the regex at hand.

Answer (score 0):

### Using `sed`

```
sed -e 's/is_tokenized_//g' -e 's/:TKN_NAME//g' /tmp/data.txt
```

#### Output

```
Firstname Last_Name
Firstname Last_Name
```

### Using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="(is_tokenized_|:TKN_NAME)"; OFS=" " } ; {print $2, $4}' /tmp/data.txt
```

- `FS` is a regex to split an input string ;
- `OFS` is a string for output separator.

#### Output

```
Firstname Last_Name
Firstname Last_Name
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh right `sed -e 's/is_tokenized_//g' -e 's/:TKN_NAME//g' /tmp/so.txt` give  the same result!

Comment: Yep! Much better as amended. Still not *quite* on-spec as it should remove any suffix starting with `:TKN_` rather than only `:TKN_NAME`, and arguably by removing those strings anywhere rather than only in prefix and suffix position it's going beyond the specified behavior, but this certainly fixes the efficiency problems.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, But wrt to AWK the print values are constant ,but is there a way I can get generic by taking into the loop .

As while processing the input may also have 2 or more sets of the same pattern.

As in the given example I have only give 2 sets,but it may vary as it can 2,or 3 or 4 sets depends.

Comment: Guys I tried with the below which solved my generic problem,Thanks every one for the hints and the help.Cheerss

awk 'BEGIN{ FS="(is_tokenized_|:TKN_NAME|)"; OFS=" " } ; {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'