# Need to split file name form _ some number in shell script

Tags: shell

I have some files in directory ,
Need to split them by _ number

Example : I have files like ODRD_AzureData_Linux_x64_19.1.0.0.7.tar,

I want to split that by

name : ODRD_AzureData_Linux_x64

version :19.1.0.0.7

I was tried with this not getting results : name='$filename | cut -f1 -d'.'' ,
I am not getting expected results ,

please help  me

Comment: Are there always precisely four `_` characters? Is the suffix always precisely `.tar,` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bash` glob parameter expansion as [explained here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417998/stripping-prefixes-and-suffixes-from-shell-words-matching-a-pattern) to extract the file name and version number and store them in bash array (assuming there are multiple files with `.tar` extension).

I have written a simple bash script for you (let's name it `listfiles.sh`), you can refer and modify it as per your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arrFiles
declare -a fname
declare -a fversion

for file in "$1"/*
do
    arrFiles=("${arrFiles[@]}" "$file")
done

idx=0
for f in "${arrFiles[@]}"
do
    extension="${f##*.*.}"
    fname=("${fname[@]}" "$(basename -s ".$extension" "${f}")")
    fversion=("${fversion[@]}" "${fname[idx]#*_[0-9]}")
#    echo ${fversion[idx]}
    idx=$((idx+1))
done

echo "FileName: " "${fname[@]%_*}"
echo "Version: " "${fversion[@]}"
```

To use it, you need to call this script on the folder where your files are stored, e.g.
`bash listfiles.sh Documents`

Comment: Well `bash` isn't POSIX `[shell]`, but aside from your use of `arrFiles`, (no arrays in POSIX shell), the basic parameter expansions involving `#` and `##` and `%` and `%%` ARE present in POSIX shell. So you may want to add a POSIX answer below your current one and just loop over `for file in "$1"/*` as the entire processing loop. There is NO need to declare `fname` and `fversion` as indexed-arrays (e.g. `declare -a ...`), a normal variable will do.

Comment: But then why is it not mentioned in GNU's manual about POSIX shell 
 https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html?

Comment: See [POSIX 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) (end of section)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin And how `parameter expansions` are working in bash if it is not a POSIX shell, why it is not complaining or throwing error on my system? Even `shellcheck` also didn't warn about it. Is that the underlying logic for interpreter is doing magic behind the stage.

Comment: They are in bash! Bash has many many more wonderful parameter expansions -- but POSIX has very few. You correctly used the one that are POSIX -- but missed that this question was tagged `[shell]` meaning POSIX shell, not `[bash]`. No dings, just making sure the distinction was clear.

Comment: `shellcheck` shouldn't complain or warn about it because of the shebang that states you are using bash instead of POSIX shell...

Answer (score 0):

It’s a little difficult to give a catch-all solution since we aren’t sure of the format or the the shell. But let’s assume this:

- Shell is BASH (Or any POSIX compliant shell)
- The format is always name_version.*

You can use parameter-expansion to solve this nicely. Using your example:

```
#!/bin/bash

<SNIPPED>

# This doesn’t have to be hard-coded, it’s just for simplicity
input=ODRD_AzureData_Linux_x64_19.1.0.0.7.tar

# Remove the lastmost ‘_’ and everything after.
name=“${input%_*}”

# Remove the lastmost ‘_’ and everything before.
version=“${input%*_}

# Remove the firstmost ‘.’ with a letter following
# and everything after.
version=“${version#.[a-zA-Z]*}

# ^ We need to do this to remove the extension.
# This may break if version includes “alpha/beta”

<SNIPPED>
```

This particular process is known as “pattern-removal”. However, Bash parameter-expansion has a lot of neat tricks up its sleeve I recommend you check out.

After reading David’s comment I’ve, learned that a subset of parameter-expansions are POSIX compliant and, adjusted my answer accordingly. Shells are beautiful things.

Comment: I’m too low level to comment on other answers, but beware that file extensions can supersede one-period (see, .tar.gz). It may be a safer bet to use ‘#’ than ‘%’ but, as the developer, you should make the call that’s best for you

Answer (score 0):

To be compatible with POSIX shell, and avoid spawning more than one process (subshell), you can use the built-in parameter-expansions supported by POSIX shell to trim from the left and right ends of the filename as needed breaking the filenames into the `name` and `ver` you desire. The basic approach is to loop over the filenames in a directory and apply the parameter expansions as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for f in *; do                # loop over each file in current directory
  [ ! -f "$f" ] && continue   # skip anything not a file
  name="${f%_*}"              # trim from right to first '_'
  ver="${f##*_}"              # trim from left to last '_'
  ver="${ver%.*}"             # trim from right to first '.'
  printf "name: %s\nver:  %s\n" "$name" "$ver"    # output results
done
```

The parameter expansions supported by POSIX are:

```
    ${var#pattern}      # Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
    ${var##pattern}     # Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
    ${var%pattern}      # Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
    ${var%%pattern}     # Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

(**note:** `pattern` can contain the normal globbing characters such as `'*'`)

**Example Output**

With your example above, you would receive the following output:

```
name: ODRD_AzureData_Linux_x64
ver:  19.1.0.0.7
```